# How to initialize an empty object of a custom UIImageView subclass

Tags: swift, uiimageview, initialization, overriding, subclass

I'm having a custom UIImageView subclass which runs some basic code like creating a shadow etc.
When I don't override any `init` everything works fine. I can create an empty `CustomImageView()` the same way I would create am empty `UIImageView()` . The moment I'm adding all the required overrides I cannot create an empty object anymore.

The error I am getting is:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ProfilePictureImageView' with no
> arguments

with the suggestion:

> 1. Overloads for 'ProfilePictureImageView' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (coder: NSCoder), (frame: CGRect), (image:
>    UIImage?)

I create the empty object in my view controller like this:

```
var customImageView = CustomImageView()
```

And my custom UIImageView subclass looks like this:

```
class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }


// Followed by my custom variables and methods.

}
```

I've tried to add the following, assuming I'm missing an empty `init` of some sort. But this didn't work either.

```
override init() {
    super.init()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to make a `convenience init` method.

```
class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    //...
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero) // or self.init(image: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what was missing! Thanks! Is any of the two versions the recommended one? `frame .zero` or `image: nil` ?

Comment: Nope. Although it's purpose is to set the default case, if required. For example if you want to set a default placeholder image or a default frame.